# How to set the disabled attribute as disabled on the first <option> of a Zend Framework 2 form

Tags: php, zend-form, zend-framework2

I´m developing an application using Zend Framework 2 and I´m using two select multiple boxes. The first is populated with data from the data base, the second is empty.

**I intend to set the disabled attribute as "disabled" in the first option of both selects.**
This way the  first options will be unusable and un-clickable. Therefor a user will not be able to pass those first options from one select to the other while using the add/remove buttons.

**Select 1**

```
   <select id="AttributesId" multiple="multiple" size="7" title="Select an Attribute" name="idAttributes[]">
   <option value="0">Please Select an Attribute</option>
    <option value="1"> Attribute 1</option>
    <option value="2"> Attribute 2</option>
   </select>
```

**Select 2**

```
<select id="SelectedAttributesId" multiple="multiple" size="7" title="Selected Attributes" name="selectedAttributes[]">
<option value="0">Current Selection</option>
</select>
```

The php code that generates both selects on ZF2 is:

(...)

```
public function __construct ($em = null)
    {
        parent::__construct("typeset");
        $this->setAttribute("method", "post")
            ->setAttribute("class", "contact-form");

        if(null !== $em)
        {
            $this->setEntityManager($em);
        }

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT a.idAttribute, a.internalName FROM ProductCatalog\Entity\Attribute\Attribute a ORDER BY a.internalName ASC");
        $attributes = $query->getResult();

        $select = new Element\Select('idAttributes');
        $select->setAttribute('title', 'Select an Attribute')
                ->setAttribute('size', 7)
                ->setAttribute('multiple', 'multiple')
                ->setAttribute('id', 'AttributesId');

        $selected = new Element\Select('selectedAttributes');
        $selected->setAttribute('title', 'Selected Attributes')
               ->setAttribute('size', 7)
               ->setAttribute('multiple', 'multiple')
               ->setAttribute('id', 'SelectedAttributesId');

        $labelIdAttributes = 'Attributes List: ';
        $labelSelectedAttributes = 'Selected Attributes List: ';

        $options[0] = 'Please Select an Attribute';
```

// this followin line doesn´t work but you can get an idea of what I need with it
//$options[0]->setAttribute('deselect', 'deselect');

```
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $value)
        {
            $options[$value['idAttribute']] = $value['internalName'];
        }

        $selectedOptions[0] = 'Current Selection';



        $select->setLabel($labelIdAttributes)
               ->setValueOptions($options);


        $selected->setLabel($labelSelectedAttributes)
                ->setValueOptions($selectedOptions);


        $this->add($select);
        $this->add($selected);

(...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly you need to format the options array slightly differently:

```
$options = array(
    array('value' => '0', 'label' => ' Please Select an Attribute', 'disabled' => 'disabled'),
    array('value' => '1', 'label' => ' Attribute 1'),
    array('value' => '2', 'label' => ' Attribute 2')
);
```

Disabled is one of the valid attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the form element and use disabled attribute

```
$form->get('select_element')->setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```